# Duplicating an email form with an onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form where a user can input there email address into a textfield, I need a way of storing this value and then when a user clicks 'Add another email' the textfield should duplicate, however i am struggling to come up with any ideas.

```
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <TextField
      className={classes.field}
      id="contactEmails"
      name="contactEmails"
      label="Contact Email(s)"
      fullWidth
      autoComplete="lname"
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: 250
      }}
    />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <Button onClick={handleEmailClick} className={classes.addButton} variant='contained' color='primary'> Add Another Email</Button>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: have an array of numbers set to the state i.e `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` but `[0]` by default and when the user clicks the buttons, push to that state array. Use `.map()` to iterate over the state array and render out a `TextField`

Comment: Suppose the user adds another email do you want the user to be able to edit the first email when required ?

Comment: or don't use numbers in the Array use some sort of decided identifier that way you can add that identifier to the `name` property of your input etc and have an identifier for your `key` prop

Comment: You can also try pushing the emails which the user wants to include into an array

Comment: @Muljayan maybe it's best to have an Array of Objects which contain the values of the `TextFields` in order to go back and edit the individual `TextField` Value, an identifier is important though in order to find and edit the specific input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all emails in an `array`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      emails: [""]
    };
  }

  handleEmail() {
    this.setState({
      emails: [...this.state.emails, '']
    });
  }

  handleChange(e, i) {
    let { emails } = this.state;
    let emailUpdate = [...emails];
    emails.splice(i, 1);

    emailUpdate[i] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      emails: emailUpdate
    });
  }

  render() {
    let { emails } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {emails.map((v, i) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input value={v} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, i)} />
              <br />
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Add Another Email"
          onClick={() => this.handleEmail()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Ashan Ali This looks great thankyou, is there any way this could be converted from a class based component into one that uses react hooks such as useState?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a component and keep count of number of text fields to render in state

```
<TextField
      className={classes.field}
      id="contactEmails"
      name="contactEmails"
      label="Contact Email(s)"
      fullWidth
      autoComplete="lname"
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: 250
      }}
    />
```

now when you click on add just increment counter and it will render an extra field

```
for(let i=0;i< this.state.counter; i++ {
  arr.push(component)
}
return arr
```